# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_CSV'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to store my extracted chrome data into a csv format using df.to_CSV

here is my code :

```
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_13oc-S'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_4rR01T'})
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_30jeq3 _1_WHN1'})
    rating=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34 _2beYZw'})
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text)
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products, 'Price':prices, 'Rating':ratings})
df.to_CSV(r'C:\Users\Krea\Documents\products.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It's spelled `df.to_csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's case-sensitive, should be `df.to_csv(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive. Change the last row to:

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Krea\Documents\products.csv', index=False)
```